# $date = new DateTime for older PHP versions

Tags: php, time

Using the code below I received an error and I found out that it has to do with my server not having the latest PHP running:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$a->metrics->duration.'S'));
```

**The Error:**
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add()

**The Question:**
How would I achieve the above for a server that is running PHP 5.2.17 ?

Comment: 5.2.* is ancient. If at all possible, you should try to get it upgraded.

Comment: I know, I will have to ask my provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of strtotime():

```
$date = strtotime ("2000-01-01");
$date = strtotime ("+900 seconds", $date); // adds 900 seconds to date
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up with:
    `$date = strtotime ("2000-01-01");
    $date = strtotime ('+900 seconds'.$a->metrics->duration.'S'. $date); // adds 900 seconds to date`

Comment: `strtotime($a->metrics->duration . " seconds", $date);` is probably what you are looking for, given that "duration" always is given in seconds.

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed that and it's working fine.. Thanks David.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = new DateTime() ;
$start->modify( '+900 seconds' ) ; 
var_dump( $start->format('h:i:s' ));
```

Using modify should still work for your version, enabling you to stick with DateTime, works for me on 5.2.6